# Why does my C function return string variable as a pointer instead of a value?

Tags: c, string, pointers

In C, I have the following function:

```
//Get Readability: Coleman-Liau Index Formula: ((0.0588 * Average # of letters per 100 words) - (0.296 * Average # of sentences per 100 words) - 15.8)
string get_readability(float avg_letters, float avg_sentences)
{
    //Store as int so that it rounds the resulting index number
    int index = (0.0588 * avg_letters) - (0.296 * avg_sentences) - 15.8;

    //printf("Index: %i\n", index);//debug

    //Return the grade level
    if (index < 1)
    {
        return "Before Grade 1";
    }
    else if (index > 16)
    {
        return "Grade 16+";
    }
    else
    {
        //Create char array for result in order to concat the index number
        char result[8] = "Grade ";
        char grade[2];
        sprintf(grade, "%i", index);//Convert int to string
        strcat(result, grade);
        //Convert char array to string in order to return results
        string result_str = result;

        return result_str;
    }
}
```

When I call it and store it in a variable it's correct and I can print it right away with no issues:

```
//Get reading level
//string reading_level = get_readability(letter_avg, sentence_avg);
string reading_level = get_readability(464.29f, 28.57f);

//printf("%i letters\n%i words\n%i sentences\n%f letter avg\n%f sentence avg\n", letter_count, word_count, sentence_count, letter_avg, sentence_avg);//debug
    
printf("%s\n", reading_level);
```

But if I do multiple printf statements between setting the variable and printing it, then the variable changes to "" and just prints a blank line.

```
//Get reading level
//string reading_level = get_readability(letter_avg, sentence_avg);
string reading_level = get_readability(464.29f, 28.57f);

//printf("%i letters\n%i words\n%i sentences\n%f letter avg\n%f sentence avg\n", letter_count, word_count, sentence_count, letter_avg, sentence_avg);//debug
printf("\n");
printf("\n");
printf("\n");

printf("%s\n", reading_level);
```

Looking this up it seems like the issue might be that when the function is returning `result_str` it's returning the pointer to that variable and after calling printf a couple times, it's getting written over. But I don't really understand how that would happen as I'm not passing anything with *.

Comment: what is `string` symbol? There is no such thing in standard C. It smells a bit like C++ has sneak in.

Comment: If you mean `return result_str;` the program has *undefined behaviour* returning a pointer to the local variable `char result[8] = "Grade ";` that will die.

Comment: Pointer types have values just like any other type does.  "A pointer instead of a value" is nonsensical.

Comment: Are you going through CS50? It unfortunately typedefs `char *` to `string` and encourages use of that.

Comment: Presumably this is cs50 which has `typedef char *string;`.

Comment: If this is the cs50 `string`, your functions should not return `string` _unless_ you used one of the cs50 functions that returned a `string`. cs50 uses `string` for `char` pointers pointing at memory that will be automatically `free`d `atexit`.

Comment: And your _"Convert char array to string in order to return results"_ is not possible like that. The `char*` (`string`) will point at the local array and be a dangling pointer when the function returns and the array goes out of scope.

Comment: This is for CS50, yes. I was under the assumption that only the cs50.h header functions were CS50 given code and everything else was standard C. So that sucks.
How would I go about replacing the 'string's with char arrays instead? CS50 hasn't taught that yet and I can't seem to find a straight answer online.

Comment: The cs50.h file declares functions and has a `typedef char* string;` so you _can_ use `string` instead of `char*` - but you'd signal the wrong thing to a reader of your code. The cs50 function `get_string` returns a `string` but you should never `free` that since that's done `atexit`. In your function, the returned `char*` _should_ be `free`d by the caller (unless you add a similar framework as cs50 to destroy it when the program exits).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
char result[8] = "Grade ";
...
string result_str = result;

return result_str;
```

First, the `string` type is unique to CS50; it's not part of standard C.  C does not have an actual *string* data type.

Second, the CS50 `string` type is not an actual *string* data type, either - it's a typedef name (alias) for a *pointer* type:

```
typedef char *string;
```

A string in C is simply a sequence of character values including a zero-valued terminator - the string `"hello"` is represented as the sequence `{'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 0}`.  Strings are *stored* in arrays of character type, but character arrays can also store sequences that are *not* strings (either don't have a 0-valued terminator, or have multiple 0-valued bytes).

Unless it is the operand of the `sizeof`, `_Alignof`, or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted, or "decay", to an expression of type "pointer to `T`" and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.  When you pass an array expression as an argument to a function, like

```
char arr[N];
foo( arr );
```

the conversion rule above replaces `arr` with a pointer expression, such that the function call looks more like

```
foo( &arr[0] );
```

and what the function receives is a pointer, not an array.  This is true for all array types, not just character arrays.

So when you write

```
string result_str = result;
```

you're storing a *pointer* to the first element of the `result` array to `result_str`, not its contents, and by extension returning that address to the caller.

Third, the `result` array is local to `get_readability` and *ceases to exist* once the function exits.  The memory that the array occupied is still there, but now it's available for other functions to use.  As long as you didn't call any other functions after `get_readability` that memory remained unmodified and your code appeared to work as expected, but as soon as you called `printf( "\n" );` that memory was overwritten.

There are two ways to go here.

The first (and IMO preferred) method is to pass the target buffer as a parameter to `get_readability` (replacing any instance of `string` with `char *` since `string` won't work outside of the CS50 environment):

```
/**
 * We're returning a pointer to the target buffer just
 * for convenience's sake.
 */
char *get_readability( float avg_letters, float avg_sentences, char *result, size_t result_size )
{
  ...
  /**
   * Using snprintf to make sure we don't write past the
   * end of the result array.
   */
  snprintf( result, result_size, "Grade %d", index );
  return result;
}
```

And you'd call it as

```
char result[8];
...
printf( "reading level: %s\n", get_readability( 464.29f, 28.57f, result, sizeof result ) );
```

Again, we're returning the `result` pointer just for convenience; you could also do:

```
char result[8];
get_readability( 464.29f, 28.57f, result, sizeof result );
printf( "Reading level: %s\n", result );
```

The second (less-preferred) option is to dynamically allocate memory within `get_readability` and return a pointer to that:

```
char *get_readability( float avg_letters, float avg_sentences )
{
  ...
  char *result = calloc( 8, sizeof *result );
  if ( result )
    snprintf( result, 8, "Grade %d", index );
  else
    // memory allocation failure, handle as appropriate
  return result;
}
```

and call it as

```
char *result = get_readablity( 464.29f, 28.57f );
printf( "Reading level: %s\n", result );
...
free( result );
```

Drawbacks to this method:

- When you're done with it, you must explicitly free the allocated memory using the `free` library function;

  To be able to do that, you must save the returned pointer value to a variable somewhere - if you write something like

  ```
  printf( "Reading level: %s\n", get_readability( 464.29f, 28.57f ) );
  ```

  then you've lost any reference to that dynamically-allocated buffer and it hangs around until the program exits.  

  You *could* do something like

  ```
  char *result;
  printf( "Reading level: %s\n", (result = get_readability( 464.29f, 28.57f ) );
  ...
  free( result );
  ```

  but it doesn't buy you that much and you'd likely get murdered by anyone maintaining your code.